# 3D Perlin Noise Normalize function in C#

Tags: python, c#, numpy, optimization, perlin-noise

I've spent the past week or two making a personalized Perlin noise generator (notice I said personalized because I don't want to use other generators), but I'm not a super-skilled programmer, and it's really slow. To speed it up, I've been looking into C#, because it's close to python and java, which are my two best languages, and it's not C. Problem is, I programmed the entire generator in python, which is not my strongest language, and had I programmed it in java I would've had an easier time converting it to C#.

Now I'm trying to translate my generator directly from python to C#, which I can do pretty easily for the most part, but I'm a little iffy on some stuff that my instructor coded for me. Namely, this normalize function:

```
# np is numpy
def normalize(img):
    img_copy=img*1.0
    img_copy-=np.min(img_copy)
    img_copy/=np.max(img_copy)
    img_copy*=255.9999
    return np.uint8(img_copy)
```

I don't know if C# can do this almost instantaneous list comprehension without excessive for-looping, and I also don't know much about NumSharp, which is what I'd use instead of numpy.

how would I write this function in C#, and how do I use the NumSharp equivalent of the numpy functions zeros(), max(), min() and the cv2 function resize?

P.S. I have the program on repl.it if you need more context.
https://repl.it/@JoshuaFavorite/PerlinNoiseGenerator#main.py

Edit: apparently it isn't clear that my python program is fully functioning and I don't need any help with that, I need help with C#. Specifically instantaneous matrix multiplication, matrix statistics and such things that are so easily done with python.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not know C#, but here is one way to generate perlin noise in Python OpenCV

```
 - Start with a black image
 - Iterate generating a noise image at different dimensions according to power law
 - Resize it
 - Attenuate it
 - Add it to the previous iteration
 - Scale to range 0 to 255 as integer
 - Save the results
```

```
import cv2
import skimage.exposure
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()

# define argument
wd = 500                # width output
ht = 500                # height of output
base = 2                #integer>1; typically 2 to 4; frequency=base^(octave level)
startlevel = 1          #starting octave level; integer>0
endlevel = 6            #ending octave level; nominally 5 or 6
atten = 0               #persistence=1/atten; amp=persist^(j-1); atten=0 -> amp=1/j; j=1,2...; atten=2 is good, also

# compute larger of wd and ht
max_dim = max(wd,ht)

#compute start dim as base^(startlevel)
start_dim = base**startlevel

# compute end dim as base^(endlevel)
end_dim = base**endlevel

# create zero frequency black base to which to add octaves
result = np.zeros((max_dim,max_dim),dtype=np.float32)

# process octaves
j = 1
for i in range (startlevel,endlevel):
    if atten == 0:
        amp = 1/j
    else:
        amp = 1/(atten**(j-1))
    print("Processing Octave Level:",i," and Amplitude:",amp)
    
    # create noise image, attenuate it, combine with zero frequency initial level
    dim = base**i
    noise = rng.integers(0,255,(dim,dim),np.uint8,True).astype(np.float32)
    
    # resize to max_dim and attenuate
    noise = amp * cv2.resize(noise, (max_dim,max_dim), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC).astype(np.float32)
    
    # add to result
    result = cv2.add(result, noise)
    
    # stop if end_dim for given endlevel is larger than max_dim
    if end_dim > max_dim:
        break
            
    # increment 
    i += 1
    j += 1

# scale to range 0 to 255, and crop to desired dimensions
result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(result, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
result = result[0:ht, 0:wd]

# save result
cv2.imwrite('perlin.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('perlin', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Atten 0, Startlevel 1 and Endlevel 6:

[image]

Atten 0, Startlevel 1 and Endlevel 5:

[image]

Atten 2, Startlevel 1 and Endlevel 6:

[image]

Comment: Well, I've already created the entire thing in python (and just to be clear, it works, I even attached my completed program to the question). My problem is that I'm trying to translate it to c#, and I don't know how to efficiently do a normalize function.

Comment: Also, I'm using variations of Worley noise, so that I can have several different noise patterns. The fact that it's slow may owe to the fact that I refuse to use interpolation.